# is it correct to use menuitem role as link

Tags: menu, accessibility, menuitem

I'm trying to write an accessible application, and I have a menu(dropdown), and each item on that menu/dropdown should be a link, is it correct to use `menuitem` role as link?

see this example:

```
<div role="menu">
    <a role="menuitem" href="...">Option 1</a>
    <a role="menuitem" href="...">Option 2</a>
    <a role="menuitem" href="...">Option 3</a>
    ...
</div>
```

if that is not correct, then what is the correct approach?

Answer (score 3):

It seems you want to make an accessible menu used for site navigation.
If not your implementation is [correct](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/menubar/examples/menubar-navigation/)

Otherwise: You shouldn't use the Menu and Menubar Pattern.

> A pattern more suited for typical site navigation with
> (possible)expandable groups of links is the [Disclosure Pattern](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/disclosure/).
> For an example, see [Example Disclosure Navigation Menu](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/disclosure/examples/disclosure-navigation/).

Source: [ARIA Authoring Practice Guide : navigation Menubar Example](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/menubar/examples/menubar-navigation/)

> This implementation of site navigation does not use the menu role
> because it does not provide the complex functionality that assistive
> technologies expect in a widget that has the menu role. Typical site
> navigation does not need all the keyboard interactions specified by
> the menu and menubar pattern.

Source: https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/disclosure/examples/disclosure-navigation/

Comment: the dropdown basically has N items, when the user clicks on one item it should redirect the user to some location

Comment: @timmetje is correct.  The `role="menu"` and `role="menuitem"` is not needed for site navigation "menus". Even though they're called "menus", they're not menus in the traditional desktop application type menus (File, Edit, View, etc).  You should rarely ever need `role="menu"`, and if you use it, you must provide arrow key navigation as in the "correct" link provide in this answer.